# How to add 2nd axis into holoviews' bokeh plot?

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh, holoviews

I want to add a **second y-axis** into a holoviews figure with bokeh backend.

In bokeh, the parameter **"extra-y-axis"** achieves that. 
After searching the holoviews API I did not find any direct command/parameter for that, so - with some hv github research - I tried it with **hooks**.
But unfortunately I am still struggling to define a finalize/initialize hook to do that.

What I tried (code from holoviews' github):

```
def twinx(plot, element):
    # Setting the second y axis range name and range
    start, end = (element.range(1))
    label = element.dimensions()[1].pprint_label
    plot.state.extra_y_ranges = {"foo": Range1d(start=start, end=end)}
    # Adding the second axis to the plot. 
    linaxis = LinearAxis(axis_label=label, y_range_name='foo')
    plot.state.add_layout(linaxis, 'left')

curve_1 = hv.Scatter(data1)
curve_2 = hv.Scatter(data2).opts(plot=dict(finalize_hooks=[twinx]), style=dict(color='red'))

curve_1*curve_2
```

The result does create a second y-axis, but **curve_2 is still plotted against the first y-axis**.

How can I solve this? Thank you!